# Java Inheritance issue - try to understand the concept

Tags: java, inheritance

i try to understand the Inheritance  concept and i have a little question.

I have two classes A and B as:

```
public class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        System.out.println ("B");
    }

    public void arik ()
    {
        System.out.println("Arik_B");
    }
    public void yosef ()
    {
        System.out.println ("Yosef");
    }

    public void superYosef()
    {
        super.yosef();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        System.out.println ("A");
    }

    public void arik ()
    {
        System.out.println ("Arik_A");
    }

    public void yosef ()
    {
        arik();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
A ab = new B();
((B) ab).superYosef();
```

The line `A ab = new B();` will print A B and this is clear.
But the line `((B) ab).superYosef();` print `Arik_B` and i don't understand why.
before running `ab` is type `A` and while running it's B so it need to print `Yosef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
A ab = new B();
```

then the variable `ab` of of type `A`, but the actual object that it refers to is of type `B`. The actual type of the object determines which method will be called, not the type of the variable.

So, when you call any method on `ab` that has been overridden in class `B`, the version from class `B` will be called.

Let's see what happens here:

```
((B) ab).superYosef();
```

You need to cast, because the method `superYosef` is only defined in class `B`.

That method calls `super.yosef();`, which will call the `yosef` method in class `A`. The `A.yosef` calls `arik`, and this method is overridden in class `B`. Note that we have called the method on an object that is actually a `B`, so the `arik` method in `B` is called, which prints `Arik_B`.

Comment: Wait.. why That method calls super.yosef(); ?

Comment: What do you mean? That's what you programmed in the `superYosef` method in class `B`, see your own code above.

Answer (score 5):

When an instance method is called on `this`, the only thing that matters is the type of the *object* on which it is called. This type is known only at *runtime*.

When an instance method is called on `super`, dynamic dispatch does not apply. The method is chosen at *compile time*.

In your code:

1. you create a `new B();` and call `B.superYosef();`
2. the call `super.yosef();` appearing in that method invokes `A.yosef()` *statically* (not subject to dynamic dispatch);
3. `A.yosef()` calls `this.arik()`—unlike above, a method called on `this` is subject to dynamic dispatch;
4. the type of `this` is `B`, therefore the method `B.yosef()` is called.

Comment: Nice explanation, as always.

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke the method:

```
((B) ab).superYosef();
```

The actual instance being referred by `ab` reference is of class `B` only. Moving further, this invocation will call method `superYosef()` method in class `B`. Now, let's go to that method:

```
public void superYosef()
{
    super.yosef();
}
```

This will call the `yosef()` method in class `A`. Due to `super`. The instance is still `B`. And then in `yosef()` method:

```
public void yosef ()
{
    arik();  // equivalent to `this.arik();`
}
```

Here you have reference `this` holding reference to instance of class `B`. You invoke `arik()`, which is overridden in class `B`, and hence the method `arik()` of class `B` is invoked. The only thing which is important here is, the actual object is of type `B`.

Comment: Why This will call the yosef() method in class A ? because you said ab reference is of class B

Comment: @user2908206 `super.yosef()` method will call the method in superclass?

Answer (score 0):

Because with the class `B` you are overwriting the method `arik`, so that's why it's accessing this method in class B.

And your `ab` variable is still a `B`.